# Getting the current location of the user for Android

Tags: android, location, cellular-network

I am building an Android application and I would like to locate the phone WITHOUT the help of GPS or Internet. Instead, I would like to locate the phone with the help of the cellular signals. How can this be achieved? 
PS. I am kind of new. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#Updates

Comment: Mind that the accuracy is very low. But every update gives you information about the accuracy. Use it well.

Answer (score 0):

You can request the system to show you location updates based on NetworkProvider. It can be done by requesting location updates with the given parameter of NETWORK_PROVIDER

for instance look below:

```
   LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)contextWrapper.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 0, this);
```

Below copied from Android Documentation

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
The first parameter in requestLocationUpdates() is the type of location provider to use (in this case, the Network Location Provider for cell tower and Wi-Fi based location).

Comment: to use this one has to have a `3G activated` and i guess user is asking for signal strength of cellular

Comment: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
The first parameter in requestLocationUpdates() is the type of location provider to use (in this case, the Network Location Provider for cell tower and Wi-Fi based location)

Comment: user_CC: Will the above code, help me get the location of the mobile without the help of Internet or Wifi? I want to get the location ONLY with the help of Cell Towers.

Comment: Yes it should do as per the documentation ...try it...it will be good hear back from you did work or not?